# Create Multiple ComObject Instances of the Same ComObject

Tags: powershell, outlook, com-interop, comobject

I wonder, is it possible to Create multiple ComObject Instances(in Powershell)?
For Example:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
```

Will create Process:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    341      14    17200      27904   249     0.39   8352 OUTLOOK
```

Now, i want to open a second Outlook Instance, even with a new Powershell session, but it's not creating a new process/instance !

There's a nice app called "ExtraOutlook" that open multiple sessions with different profiles but for my specific scenarion it not help.
Do you know if it Can be done with ComObject as well?

[image: ExtraOutlook Image]

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook is a singleton. And it is a singleton on purpose. When a new instance is launched, it checks if there is a previous instance is running, and switches to that instance.

Why are you trying to run multiple instances of Outlook?

Comment: so how's the extraoutlook open multiple instances of outlook? for you second question, i'm doing mail migrations and want to process multiple sessions at once

Comment: You can use a low-level API - Extended MAPI which can be used on secondary threads.

Comment: I don't know how extraoutlook does it, they either trick the COM system(ROT - Running Objects Table) or the way Outlook detects multiple instances. If using Redemption an option? It allows to open multiple MAPI session either with existing profiles (RDOSession.Logon) or one-off temporary profiles (RDOSession.LogonExchaneMailbox / LogonHostedExchaneMailbox / LogonPstStore).

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev. In PowerShell? Even in C++ or Delphi it would be hard for somebody who has never does that. And it is guaranteed to be impossible in PowerShell.

Comment: There is Redemption for that :)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko thanks, can you think of any possibilty to achieve that anyway? can you provide more info on that redemption?

Comment: For the Redemption info, see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm. I don't think you'd be able to do what ExtraOutlook does in PowerShell.